# MySQL Insert Performance

Tags: mysql

i've been tasked to check whether MySQL can be used for Large DataWareHousing
Requirement is as following
the Table contains 83 column
each row pay load size is 1272 bytes
the requirement is the DB should be handled 150,000 Inserts of above mentioned row's per second,
currently i was been able to go past 20K using innoDB with data files set in a RAM Disk

```
tmp-table-size                 = 320M
max-heap-table-size            = 320M
query-cache-type               = 0
query-cache-size               = 0
max-connections                = 500
thread-cache-size              = 50
open-files-limit               = 65535
table-definition-cache         = 1024
table-open-cache               = 2048
innodb_write_io_threads         = 8
innodb_read_io_threads          = 8
innodb_thread_concurrency       = 12
innodb-flush-method            = O_DIRECT
innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
innodb-log-file-size           = 512M
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 1
innodb-file-per-table          = ON
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 20G

innodb_buffer_pool_instances   = 12 
innodb_log_buffer_size         = 10M
```

Comment: Have you stopped to think about what little you can do with the resulting 700GB table after loading for an hour?

Comment: Well, with the right ENGINE, configuration and hardware you can do like 400,000-600,000 inserts/s http://www.percona.com/blog/2013/09/05/tokudb-vs-innodb-timeseries-insert-benchmark/ http://www.percona.com/blog/2013/08/29/considering-tokudb-as-an-engine-for-timeseries-data/ A very different thing is if you should be doing that on the first place, and if that is the right tool, or you should use, alternativelly, a data warehousing solution.

Comment: 600K is not sustainable.  You will hit a brick wall soon after the amount of data being inserted exceeds what can be cached in RAM.  (The first link shows 40G buffer_pool for 82GB of data.  And no secondary indexes.)ff

Answer (score 1):

For InnoDB on a RAM disk:

- innodb_flush_log_on_trx_commit = 1
- innodb_doublewrite = OFF
- batch inserts (100-1000 per transaction)
- probably other settings

Better yet, use ENGINE=MEMORY, not InnoDB -- Either way, your data will be lost in a power failure.

If you need high speed, multi-threaded ingestion, see  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table